# Java коллекции и основные группы

Tags: java

Прочитал в книге: В Java коллекции делятся на три основных группы: List — список, Set — множество, Map — словарь, а где Queue она же очередь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очередь это не коллекция, а структура данных, работающая по принципу FIFO (первый вошёл - первый вышел).

Если Вам нужна очередь, в Java есть интерфейс `Queue`.

В Java он наследуется от интерфейса `Collection` и т.о. получается, что очередь в Java выступает подмножеством коллекций, но по своей логике (сравните с тем же `List`) "классической" коллекцией её сложно назвать.

Comment: так-то интерфейс Queue extends Collection

Comment: Ну получается "очередь" входит в Коллекции? Раз интерфейс Queue расширяет Collection и объявляет поведение очередей, которые представляют собой список с дисциплиной "первый вошел первый вышел“ (FIFO).

Comment: @MikeMclaren, формально очередь можно отнести к коллекциям, но по факту это самостоятельная структура данных.

Comment: @Streletz Получается правильней будет сказать вот так: В Java коллекции делятся на четыре основных группы: List — список, Set — множество, Map — словарь, Queue - очередь (интерфейс который определяет очереди) или же лучше оставить так как было?

Comment: Если исходить из документации, то очередь, дек и даже стек можно отнести к коллекциям. Отчасти это справедливо, т.к. у них есть некоторое сходство (иначе тот же Queue не было бы никакого смысла наследовать от Collection). Но в целом с точки зрения логики их основная задача даже не столько хранение данных, сколько организация работы с ними. Поэтому они не относятся к "классическим" коллекциям. Видимо автор книги, которую Вы читали исходил и аналогичных соображений.

Comment: Однако, вопрос философский. ИМХО, наследуется от Collection - значит коллекция!